# Use a .wav file in C++ in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I'm trying to read a .wav file from my Xcode files to use it in a C++ function that is located in a C++ library inside my Xcode project. I don't know where do I need to put the file (in which group or even in which target) so the C++ function can read it. I also need to call the function from swift because it is an iOS project. This is the two C++ functions that use the file:

```
EXPORT
string getMark()
{
  std::string result;
  result = get_watermark("piano2.wav", "");

  return (result.c_str());
}
```

This is the other one:

```
std::string get_watermark (const string& infile, const string& orig_pattern)
{
    std::string patterns;
    WavData wav_data;
    Error err = wav_data.load (infile);
    if (err)
    {
        error ("audiowmark: error loading %s: %s\n", infile.c_str(), err.message());
        return "1";
    }

    if (Params::test_truncate)
    {
        const size_t  want_n_samples = wav_data.sample_rate() * wav_data.n_channels() * Params::test_truncate;
        vector<float> short_samples  = wav_data.samples();

        if (want_n_samples < short_samples.size())
        {
            short_samples.resize (want_n_samples);
            wav_data.set_samples (short_samples);
        }
    }

    int result;
    if (wav_data.sample_rate() == Params::mark_sample_rate)
    {
        result = decode_and_report (wav_data, orig_pattern);
        
        if (PatternStorage::getInstance().getPatterns() != "") {
            patterns = PatternStorage::getInstance().getPatterns();
        }

        return patterns;
    }
    else
    {
        result = decode_and_report (resample (wav_data, Params::mark_sample_rate), orig_pattern);
        
        if (PatternStorage::getInstance().getPatterns() != "") {
            patterns = PatternStorage::getInstance().getPatterns();
        }

        return patterns;
    }
}
```

This is an example of how I call a C++ function from the actual swift project.

cpp file:

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))

EXPORT
string get_wm_string () {
  string hello = "Hello from C++";
  return hello;
}
```

.h file:

```
extern const char* get_wm_string(void);

@interface WatermarkLib : NSObject

- (void)getCPPString;

@end
```

.mm file:

```
@implementation WatermarkLib

- (void)getCPPString {
  NSString* externalString = [NSString stringWithCString:get_wm_string() encoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
  NSLog(@"Exito! %@", externalString);
}

@end
```

This is how the working directory looks like from Xcode:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your problem that the file can't be found?

Comment: It says that there is no such file called "piano2.wav". The file is in the project

Comment: Your app will execute in a current working directory. This probably set by Xcode if you execute your app from Xcode. If you execute your app from the console your working directory is where you are standing.  The path given needs to take this into consideration.

Comment: The application itself has no understanding of your project structure.

Comment: Yes, I understand. What I meant with the question was: do I have to do something special with the code that I have? And do I have to put the file in a specific folder so de .cpp file can read it?

Comment: Remember that it is your executable that reads the file, not the cpp file. So the relative directory has to be relative to the working directory of the execution. Maybe start by giving the filename as a full complete path. (from the root).

Comment: I tried that and didn't work. I updated the question and included the working directory. I tried passing the path of the piano2.wav file but still doesn't read it